Entity Framework Core is logging every query to the event log
This is strange: I have published a .NET Core 8 web application that uses Entity Framework Core to access a SQL Server database.
The application works, but when I see the event log, I find a lot of information entries with all queries executed by Entity Framework Core.
When I add the DbContext I use this code:
services.AddDbContext<SecuWebModulesVisitorControlContext>(options =>
         {
             options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Modules.VisitorControl"), o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery));
#if DEBUG
             options.LogTo(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
#endif
        });

When in release compilation, that LogTo method is not called.
What may be happening?
Jaime

EF Core doesn't log to the Event Log at all unless not just EF but the logging library too are explicitly configured to do so. EF Core doesn't use the Event Log by default because it only exists on Windows

Unless by event log you mean the log file? Without the logging configuration we can't guess what the application is doing
